# GetTypes in an assembly without using dependencies assemblies

Tags: c#, .net-assembly

I have a C# assembly but I dont have its dependencies assemblies.

Is there any way to GetTypes() of the .Net assembly without having its dependencies assembly.

```
 Assembly SampleAssembly;
 SampleAssembly = Assembly.LoadFrom(@"AnyExternal.dll");
 var mytypes = SampleAssembly.GetExportedTypes();
```

I have the AnyExternal.dll but I dont have the dependencies of it.

Is it possible.

Comment: But when I try to load it . it throws exception.

Comment: You can't obtain `Type` from assembly (even if it was loaded using `ReflectionOnlyLoad`), if that type uses somehow types from referenced assembly. Better explain, what are you going to do with these types.

Comment: I want to store these types in Database for some audit purpose. I just need the Types as strings.

Comment: `ildasm /text /classlist /noil NameOfDll` will give you a list of types in an assembly, and doesn't need to be able to find dependencies.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that's what I was looking for.

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/3262/A-NET-assembly-viewer

This viewer does not use any third party and can extract assembly infor.

Answer (score 3):

Since you want just to discover type *names*, [Mono.Cecil](http://www.mono-project.com/docs/tools+libraries/libraries/Mono.Cecil/) can help you:

```
var types = AssemblyDefinition
    .ReadAssembly("YourAssembly.dll")
    .MainModule
    .Types
    .Where(_ => _.IsPublic);
```

Note, that `Where(_ => _.IsPublic)` isn't a strict equivalent of `Assembly.GetExportedTypes`, since the last one also returns nested public types.

To add Mono.Cecil to your project, execute:

```
Install-Package Mono.Cecil
```

from Package Manager Console.

Comment: Can it also provide you the base type of a public type.

Comment: If you mean "*name* of the base type", then yes, this is possible too - `type.BaseType.Name`/``type.BaseType.FullName``.

Comment: That's what I want but without using any third party.

Comment: This is rather strange requirement. Cecil is free and is delivered as NuGet package. If you want to do this by yourself, you will need to explore raw assembly metadata from your code, because reflection API can't do what you want.

Comment: I strongly suspected there'd be a way to do this via Cecil, but I've never had a need to use it in anger.